# InfluxDb external configuration on Windows

Tags: influxdb

I'm trying to use external configuration on InfluxDB running on Windows,
I've change meta, data, and wal to windows path but getting the following error:

> run: parse config: Near line 29 (last key parsed 'meta.dir'): Expected
>   eight hexadecimal digits after '\U', but got 'C:\Us' instead.

```
[meta]
  # Where the metadata/raft database is stored
  #dir = "/var/lib/influxdb/meta"
  dir = "C:\Users\User01\.influxdb\meta"
```

https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/blob/master/etc/config.sample.toml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay, sloved.. needed to use double quotes...

```
dir = "C:\Users\User01\.influxdb\meta"
```